# Attribute selector not working on a table when attribute is 'width'

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Firefox 36.2

My page has no `doctype` defined.

Has nested tables and one of them has `width="50%"`.

I am trying to select that table and set it's width to 100%.

So far nothing I did seem to work. Specifically, the only way to uniquely identify this particular table in this particular page alone (since we have a common styles file for all pages), is identifying the form that has a specific action value in it. When I tried `[action="MYTARGET"]` didn't work either. In general attribute selectors do not seem to work?

Ideally to uniquely select my table and set its width, I want to do this (since that's the only table that has a width attribute defined on the page):

```
form[action="MYTARGET"] table[width] {width:auto;}
```

Any ideas? Once I figure this out in firefox then I have the herculian task of getting this work in IE9+.

But first things first .....

**EDIT:**
My basic issue is, when I start trying my approach and type the new new rule in firebug styles section, the rule just disappears. So somehow firefox doesn't even like it and is ignoring it altogether. If I see a strikethrough on my new rule, at least I am happy to see that. But that doesn't happen. (as you can tell I do not deal with styling usually, so am a newbie trying to fix something quick)

I do not have access to edit the html itself. I only have access to edit the styles files.

**EDIT2:**
Iqbal's comments made me try adding the rule via 'css' tab and not 'style' tab and the rule seems to stay. So I think where I place my rule is making a difference (I thought it shouldn't, atleast the rule shouldn't disappear). I will research some more and come up with an explanation.

Comment: _Doesn't working in Firefox_: To further the process of elimination, try it in Google Chrome's developer console. If it works we can narrow it down to a browser issue, if it doesn't then it's probably your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using the whole code as selector. i.e. `form[action="MYTARGET"] table[width] {width:100%;}`

Right click on Style tab panel of firebug > Add Rule > now type your selector i.e. `form[action="MYTARGET"] table[width]` > now add your styles.

Comment: I made an edit to the post. The rule I type, just disappears :(

Comment: I think I am doing the typing as I should. I see the braces automatically created, I type the width property there as I should. But as soon as I click out of it, my rule disappears

Comment: Any other rules without the attribute selectors, stay fine.

Comment: you are partly right. When I click on the CSS tab and put my rule there, it stays! But in the Style tab (I can not seem to right the tab itself by the way), when right click randomly somewhere in the style section and then add the rule, it disappears. But only those rules with a attribute. Since you  selection in it seem to disappear. others seem to stay. Makes me think, that the specific section where I right click and add the rule, somehow has a say on the rule.